# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression when update table using other table records

Tags: sql, .net, winforms, visual-studio

When trying to execute this SQL statement, I get error :

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression Orders.BuyPrice" From Pro INNER JOIN Orders On Pro.ProID = Orders.ProID

Trying to Update Balance and BuyPrice in Pro Table from Orders table

```
dim query as string = "update Pro set Pro.Balance = Pro.Balance + Orders.Qu," & _
"Pro.BuyPrice = Orders.BuyPrice" & _
" From Pro INNER JOIN Orders On Pro.ProID = Orders.ProID " & _
"AND orders.OrderID = " & orderID

execute(query)
```

Execute:

```
execute(q as string)
connectDB
dim cmd as new ODBCCommand(q, DBcon) 
cmd.executeNonQuery()
```

I don't know what is wrong in query?

Comment: What database (DBMS) you're using? Is it SQL Server or MySQL or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODBC use MySql so try this code

```
update 
      Pro 
Inner join orders 
      on 
Pro.ProID = Orders.ProID
      set 
Pro.Balance = Pro.Balance + Orders.Qu,
Pro.BuyPrice = Orders.BuyPrice
      where 
orders.OrderID = orderID
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "ODBC use MySql"?

Comment: user use odbc connction from this line in his code <code> dim cmd as new ODBCCommand(q, DBcon) <code> , so he must use SQL statments like in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can not do a join within an update query. You have to do a select query first to retrieve Orders.Qu and Orders.BuyPrice and use the result in your update query which will looks like:

```
dim query as string = "update Pro set Pro.Balance = Pro.Balance + " & qu & ", Pro.BuyPrice = " & buy_price & ";"
```

Comment: thanks for reply but in this case i must loop on orders to read Qu and price , i don't need that. i believe i can do it in one query like discussed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server/2334741#2334741) but i failed to implement it

Answer (score 0):

This query worked with me

```
Query = " update Pro Inner join orders on Pro.ProID = Orders.ProID " & _
"set Pro.Balance = Pro.Balance + Orders.Qu," & _
"Pro.BuyPrice = Orders.BuyPrice" & _
" where orders.OrderID = " & orderID
```